# Ignore special characters in file read

Tags: python

Trying to read only words that contain alphabetical content from a file and insert into a list.

```
def readWords(x,y):
    with open(x,'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            for word in line.split():
                y.append(word)  

firstFile = sys.argv[1]
firstList = []
readWords(firstFile, firstList)
```

Example file:

```
car */ /*one lemon grass
food accelerate
```

**How do I modify this to read in every word except special characters(only alphabetical content, no punctuation symbols, or digits)**? i.e the end result being:

```
[car, one, lemon, grass, food, accelerate]
```

Comment: Regex would be best here. You can use the '\s' condition to capture special characters

Comment: @Adib `\s` captures whitespace.

Comment: @Scherf Which characters are special to you?

Comment: Good point. Sorry, it's '\W', not '\s'

Comment: @ChrisMartin only alphabetical content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest solution that filters space and special characters:

```
filter(None, re.split(r'\W|\d', bleh))
```

**The Regex**

The regex expression '\W' basically means 'catch' any non-word characters, and \d means you want to catch number characters. So if you have a word like:

> banana " *#12312 Sugar

It'll catch the complete non-word characters:

> " *#12312

**The Regex Function Split**

This code:

```
re.split(r'\W|\d', bleh)
```

Is similar to split that you used, except it's cool because it's regex-driven, which gives you some amazing capabilities.

**Filter Function**

Literally filters the list from the thing you don't want. So, in this code, where foo is a list, where foo = ["A","B","","D"]:

```
filter(None, foo)
```

It basically looks inside the list and find instances of 'None', and pop/remove it from the list.

**Full code:**

```
import re
bleh = """"car */12314 34234  /*one 123123lemon grass
food accelerate
"""
print filter(None, re.split(r'\W|\d', bleh))
```

Result:

```
['car', 'one', 'lemon', 'grass', 'food', 'accelerate']
```

**WITH YOUR CODE**

```
import re
def readWords(x,y):
    with open(x,'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            # Append to y
            y += filter(None, re.split(r'\W|\d', line))

firstFile = sys.argv[1]
firstList = []
readWords(firstFile, firstList)
```

Comment: I would split on `\W+` to decrease number of matches

Comment: @user3159253 Good recommendation!

Comment: This seems to give each word wrapped in its own list? Also testing on a different file does not prevent digits from being read. Getting results like ['21333']

Comment: @Scherf fixed the regex to catch number/digits and special characters

Comment: @Scherf also, fixed the appending problem

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for. (also replaced bleh in the append comment)